# Why do we need to define .data and .text section in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm reading an assembly book. The book explains that there are .text and .data section in a computer's memory. An example in the book also use the following source code.

```
[SECTION .data]

[SECTION .text]
```

since the above code snippet is written in assembly, I have a question.

Do .data and .text codes separated in physical memory (if so why? and does CPU care?) ? or is it just us (human) to separate them in the assembly language?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Text section of application is read-only while Data is not. Many OS load Text section into memory only once no matter how many times application was launched. This reduce memory usage and launch time and is safe because code doesn't change.
Data section contains informations that could be changed during application execution and this section must be copied for every instance.

Comment: // so...is this OS specified? Let's say I'm writing my own OS (not going to do it :) ), do I need to follow this convention?

Comment: It would be wise to keep them separate, because then you can do things to each section that are relevant to that section. For example, you may want to design different memory swap in/out rules, memory protection code and contiguous storage enforcements to these different parts of the program.

Comment: Yes I think this is OS specific and you don't need to follow this convention in your own OS. Even now OS allow changing text section from read-only to read-write and writing into it for example during debugging application or some debugging API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx.
But for normal usage not in your OS I will follow this rule.